# Ajax is working only the first time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**This is the situation:**

In my codeigniter app, a kind of social network demo, am developing the LIKE button.

When reading through the posts using a foreach loop, a like button is displayed after each post.
The first time it work properly: Ajax sends the data to the codeigniter method, the data are inserted into the table and the button become green (succesfull).
THEN it stops to work.
Even if I refresh the page, the call is not triggered anymore.

**What I have tried to do:**

Have seen all the other answers in Stack Overflow and other forums, but no one fixed the problem.
Anyway the codeigniter part is correct, the problem is with my Ajax calling.

Have simplify it for debug purpose and right now I have a very very simple Ajax function with server side disable, the only thing that should do is to make the buttons green when clicking on them.
And again it works only the first time and then does not work anymore...

**This is the HTML:**

```
<button id="button_like" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</button>
```

**This the Ajax call:**

```
$('#button_like').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

// alert('click');

var data = {
  user_id: '5',  // for debug
  post_id: '6',  // for debug
  ajax: '1' 

};

$.ajax({

  url: "<?php echo site_url('post/like'); ?>",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function() {
   $('#button_like').replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>');
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }, 

});

//  return false;
```

});

**This the question:**

How can i do to make a simple Ajax call working every time?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

Thanks you guys for all the answers.
I have made button_like a class instead of ID.

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button_like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</button>
```

And then call the function in this way:

```
  $('.button_like').on('click', function(e) {
```

And the success in this way:

```
  success: function() {
   $('.button_like').replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>');
  },
```

But now, after clicking on one button, it makes green ALL the buttons.
How can i do to make green only the one i click on?
Thank you!

**EDIT 2:**

I have recreated the situation in this Jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/xulaxowa/1/edit

Comment: You're replacing the button with another button, what did you expect? The button is now gone, and the new button has no event handler.

Comment: I feel you should change the button type submit to button and write the code for form submit after that

Comment: Ids must be unique on javascript, try to replace it by class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, i have resolved in this way:

Through the foreach loop I assign to the button ID the corresponding post ID.

Then in the Ajax function I detect the current ID and modify only this element. 
You can see this working example:

```
$('.button_like').on('click', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

//Grab the current button's ID property
var clicked = $(this).attr('id');

 //Alert the ID
 alert(clicked);

var data = {
  user_id: '5',
  post_id: '6',
  ajax: '1'  

};


$.ajax({

  url: "<?php echo site_url('post/like'); ?>",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  success: function() {
   $('#'+clicked).replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>');
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }, 

  });


});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using an ID for the element in which you attach the event. Does that mean you're having the same ID repeated several times on the page? If that's the case, jQuery will only add the event to the first one it finds... because it only expects one ID per page.

Try using classes instead, see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Have understood the mistake about using the same ID for many buttons. I edit and use class. But now all the buttons are becoming green..

Comment: Because of a common selector that's being applied? If so, then create a separate/agnostic class for those buttons only and you should be fine, as long as it's a CSS only issue. Try changing your markup if you can (and if it helps)

Answer (score 2):

You need event delegation for dynamically generated/added DOM. Use `.on()` method:

```
  $(document).on('click','.btn-success',function(){
      //click event for button code here
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are replacing the existing button. You need to add events for newly created button using delegates,

try

```
$(document).on("click",".btn-success",function(){
e.preventDefault();

// alert('click');

var data = {
  user_id: '5',  // for debug
  post_id: '6',  // for debug
  ajax: '1' 

};

$.ajax({

  url: "<?php echo site_url('post/like'); ?>",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function() {
   $('#button_like').replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>');
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }, 

});
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is down to you removing the ID from the button on your success function?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the `element` means you are loosing the same from `DOM` so its `click event` also removed, for this you need to bind `click event` again and again

Better is to change your `classes` of element and `span text`

Change the `success callback` like,

```
success: function() {
    $('#button_like').addClass('btn-success')// add new class
                     .removeClass('btn-primary') //remove primary class
                     .find('span').text(''); // empty span's text
},
```

**Updated** if you want to use `class` instead of `id` then try this,

```
var $this=$(this); // make a copy of current button object
$.ajax({
   url: "/",
   type: 'POST',
   data: data,
   success: function() {
      $this.addClass('btn-success')// add new class to current clicked button
           .removeClass('btn-primary')// remove old class
           .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>');//removing text
   },
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
         alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
   }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/xulaxowa/7/edit)

If you want that user can click only once then use **[one()](http://api.jquery.com/one)**

[One demo](http://jsbin.com/xulaxowa/8/edit)

Comment: Your reply is interesting. I have try to apply in the Jsbin i have created, but unfortunately is not working. Can you please apply it to the Jsbin?

Comment: Before any update of your question, you were using `#button_like` and now you want to use `.button_like` `class` instead of `id`, anyway I changed it see [this demo](http://jsbin.com/xulaxowa/7) and my updated `answer`.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, ...)` by `error: function(xhr, ...)` and replace :

```
$('#button_like').replaceWith(...);
```

by :

```
$('#button_like').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>').addClass('liked');
```